# How to pass the value using keypress event of asp textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, eval, request.querystring

Hi i am writing asp textbox controls. I want my pass the id using keypress event. Below code i am using but i m getting error.

The server tag is not well formed.

.aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Enabled="false">

<asp:TextBox ID="tbxValue" onkeyup="LoadAttributeValueLong("<%# Eval("ID") %>")" runat="server" 
 MaxLength="40" Text='<%# Eval("VALUE") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

If anyone have any idea than please help me in this..

Comment: Do you need the "tbxId" string or a data field?

Comment: i need the id which is from query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding expressions can't start from the middle of an attribute value. You need to write it like that:

```
<asp:TextBox onkeyup='<%# "LoadAttributeValueLong(" + Eval("ID") + ")" %>'
```

To pass also the value of the tbxId textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox onkeyup='<%# "LoadAttributeValueLong(" + Eval("ID") + ",\"" + tbxId.ClientID + "\")" %>'
```

And in your js function:

```
LoadAttributeValueLong(id, tbxId)
{
   var tbxIdValue = $('#' + tbxId).val(); // jquery version
   var tbxIdValue = document.getElementById(tbxId).value; // non jquery version
}
```

Comment: for information, how to pass the textbox value in onkeyup event

Comment: The value is client side property, so you just add "this" as a second param and in the function take what you need from it '<%# "LoadAttributeValueLong(" + Eval("ID") + ", this)" %>'

Comment: if i use 'this' the current textbox value only passing correct. I need the tbxId value into tbxValue onkeyup event.

Comment: I m getting an Error- The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: Changed my answer. Copy and try again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18574/discussion-between-prince-antony-g-and-amiram-korach)